# how to resolve Null pointer exception in java using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am running the code displayed below in Selenium Webdriver. I am creating the `m1` object of class `SalesForceApplicationMethod()`, then accessing the `.validation()` method. The code is going inside the method (`.validation()`), but it is giving the following error:

**Error trace-back:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditi‌​ons.java:212) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.‌​java:102) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDrive‌​rWait.java:71) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDrive‌​rWait.java:45) at com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.validation(Sa‌​lesForceApplicationM‌​ethod.java:27) at com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.main(SalesFor‌​ceApplicationMethod.‌​java:88)

**My code:**

```
package com.syntel.pratice;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SalesForceApplicationMethod
{
  WebDriver driver;
  public void validation()
  {

    // App launcher clicking
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,25);
    WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='label slds-truncate slds-text-link']")));
    ele.click();

    // New button
    WebElement newBtn1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'New')]"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newBtn1);

    // Account name - first account
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input uiInput uiInputText 
    uiInput--default uiInput--input']")).sendKeys("srieedherks");

    // Click Save
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='slds-button slds-button--neutral uiButton--default uiButton--brand uiButton forceActionButton']")).click();

    // Clicking new contact button
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
    WebElement newbt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'New 
    Contact')]"));
    JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    exe.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("--None--"));
    ele1.sendKeys("Mr.");
    System.out.println("Selecting ");

    // Entering first name
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='compoundBorderBottom form-
    element__row input']")).sendKeys("srieedher");

    // Entering last name
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='compoundBLRadius 
    compoundBRRadius form-element__row input']")).sendKeys("santhakumar");

    // Click Save
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='slds-button slds-button--
    brand cuf-publisherShareButton undefined uiButton']")).click();

    // Logout view profile
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='https://c.ap5.content.force.com/pro
    filephoto/005/T/1']")).click();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);

    // Click log out   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'profile-link-label 
    logout uiOutputURL')]")).click();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
    o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    o.addArguments("--start-maximized");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("srieedher@force.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Sriee678$");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your otp:");
    String i = s.next().toString();
    System.out.println("the OTP is : "+i);
    driver.findElement(By.id("smc")).sendKeys(i);
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-icon-Waffle']")).click();

    SalesForceApplicationMethod m1 = new  SalesForceApplicationMethod();
    m1.validation();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message ?

Comment: Like @Asew pointed out, w/o the complete error trace-back, it's pretty hard to debug your problem. `The code is going inside the method` (which method?) `but it is giving error as Null Pointer Exception in first line of method` (which is the first line?) isn't giving us any information what-so-ever. :)

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar You did not set `driver` for the `m1` instance

Comment: @Asew, error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
 at com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.validation(SalesForceApplicationMethod.java:27)
 at com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.main(SalesForceApplicationMethod.java:88)
 please help me.

Comment: @iamdanchiv,  error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
 at com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.validation(SalesForceApplicationMethod.java:27)
 at 
 com.syntel.pratice.SalesForceApplicationMethod.main(SalesForceApplicationMethod.java:88)

Comment: @Alex K, please send me code for driver instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the driver in the `SalesForceApplicationMethod` class is not initialized. Add the below constructor in that class.

```
public SalesForceApplicationMethod(WebDriver ldriver)
{
    this.driver=ldriver;
}
```

In the main class while creating an instance of this class, pass your `WebDriver`.

```
SalesForceApplicationMethod m1 = new  SalesForceApplicationMethod(driver);
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much . code is running fine. I want code for log out

Comment: can you post it as a separate question since the actual issue has been resolved

Comment: i will post as a separate question.

Comment: Question to be asked only in 90 minutes . I will ask the question after 90 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a global variable
 *WebDriver driver;*
and then in function main() you have written

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

which will be a local variable to main() function block. A simple thing that can be done is initialising the global variable instead of creating a new local variable of same name. For that , just replace the above line of code in main() block with

```
   driver = new ChromeDriver(o);
```

This will initialise you global variable declared at the beginning of the class.